# How do I find out google translate web service is accessing my website?

Tags: php, google-translator-toolkit

I'm using google translate for my website, and I need to make customized translations on some parts of it.  However, my website requires log in. So when I access a page I want to translate in google translate toolkit, it's stuck at the login page.  I want to bypass this by allowing my website to figure when it's being accessed by google translate, and automatically login.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still relevant today but the `User-Agent` string used to contain the string `via translate.google.com`. There's a list of Google Crawlers here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en ... but it doesn't mention translate.

It's likely a bad idea to allow Google translate to bypass login. If the resources on your site require login anyone can access protected resources by using Google translate, or by sending a crafted request that pretends to be Google translate.